# Error in Solution to $\frac{1}{\phi(n)}$ Bound

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, solution-verification

While proving the standard expression for $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{\phi(n)}$, my solution seems to claim  that

$$\sum_{y \le x} \sum_{d > x/y} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{d\varphi(d)} \cdot \frac{1}{y} = \sum_{d = 1}^\infty \frac{\mu^2(d) \log(d)}{d\varphi(d)} + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

with the proof

\begin{align*}
    &\sum_{y \le x} \sum_{d > x/y} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{d\varphi(d)} \cdot \frac{1}{y} > 
    \int_{1}^{x+1} \sum_{d > x/y} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{d\varphi(d)} \frac{1}{y}\ dy = \\
    &\sum_{d = 1}^\infty \int_{x/d}^{x+1} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{d\varphi(d)} \frac{1}{y}\ dy =
    \log\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right) \sum_{d = 1}^\infty \frac{\mu^2(d)}{d\varphi(d)} + \sum_{d = 1}^\infty \frac{\mu^2(d) \log(d)}{d\varphi(d)} \\
    &> \sum_{2 \le y \le x} \sum_{d > x/y} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{d\varphi(d)} \cdot \frac{1}{y}.\end{align*}

as $\sum_{d \ge x} \frac{1}{d \phi(d)} = O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ and $\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right) = O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ as well.

However, this seems to imply an extremely strong $O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ error bound for the entire result, which seems to suggest the more likely fact that I've messed up in this claim somewhere.

Any help is appreciated on finding exactly where that happens.

Comment: The calculation seems correct to me. Can you say more about why you think this error term is incorrect?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this implies a stronger result than (1.5) of https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-15/issue-2/On-an-error-term-of-Landau-II/10.1216/RMJ-1985-15-2-579.full, which seems to use more sophisticated techniques.

Comment: Maybe the details of that implication are important enough to include in the question then.